# Non-greedy multi-line and single-line matching

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to modify a flex+bison generator to allow the inclusion of code snippets denoted by surrounding '{{' and '}}'. Unlike the multi-line comment case, I must capture all of the content.

My attempts either fail in the case where the '{{' and the '}}' are on the same line or they are painfully slow.

My first attempt was something like this:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
// sscce implementation of a growing string buffer
char codeBlock[4096];
int codeOffset;
const char* curFilename = "file.l";
extern int yylineno;

void add_code_line(const char* yytext)
{
    codeOffset += sprintf(codeBlock + codeOffset, "#line %u \"%s\"\n\t%s\n", yylineno, curFilename, yytext);
}

%}

%option stack
%option yylineno

%x CODE_FRAG

%%

"{{"[ \n]*          { codeOffset = 0; yy_push_state(CODE_FRAG); }
<CODE_FRAG>"}}"     { codeBlock[codeOffset] = 0; printf("// code\n%s\n", codeBlock); yy_pop_state(); }
<CODE_FRAG>[^\n]*   { add_code_line(yytext); }
<CODE_FRAG>\n

\n
.
```

Note: the "codeBlock" implementation is a contrivance for the purpose of an SSCCE only. It's not what I'm actually using.

This works for a simple test case:

```
{{ from line 1
from line 2
}}

{{

from line 7
}}
```

Outputs

```
// code
#line 1 "file.l"
    from line 1
#line 2 "file.l"
    from line 2

// code
#line 7 "file.l"
    from line 7
```

But it can't handle

```
{{ hello }}
```

The two solutions I can think of are:

```
    /* capture character-by-character */
    <CODE_FRAG>.  { add_code_character(yytext[0]); }
```

And

```
    <INITIAL>"{{".*?"}}" { int n = strlen(yytext); yytext + (n - 2) = 0; add_code(yytext + 2); }
```

The former seems likely to be slow, and the latter just feels wrong.

Any ideas?

--- EDIT ---

The following appears to achieve the result desired, but I'm not sure if it's a "good" Flex way to do this:

```
"{{"[ \n]*          { codeOffset = 0; yy_push_state(CODE_FRAG); }
<CODE_FRAG>"}}"     { codeBlock[codeOffset] = 0; printf("// code\n%s\n", codeBlock); yy_pop_state(); }
<CODE_FRAG>.*?/"}}" { add_code_line(yytext); }
<CODE_FRAG>.*?      { add_code_line(yytext); }
<CODE_FRAG>\n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Flex doesn't implement non-greedy matches. So `.*?` won't work the way you expect it to in flex. (It will be an optional `.*`, which is indistinguishable from `.*`)
2. Here's a regular expression which will match from `{{` as far as possible without a `}}`:

   `"{{"([}]?[^}])*`
3. That might not be what you want, since it won't allow nested `{{...}}` within your code blocks. However, you didn't mention that as a requirement and none of your examples functions that way.
4. The above regular expression does *not* match the closing `}}`, which appears to be what you want since it lets you call `add_code(yytext+2)` without modifying the temporary buffer. However, you do need to deal with the `}}` in your action. See below.
5. The regular expression above will match to the end of the file if there is no matching `}}`. You probably want to deal with that as an error; the simplest way is to check if EOF is encountered while you are trying to ignore the `}}`

   ```
   "{{"([}]?[^}])*   { add_code(yytext+2);
                       if (input() == EOF || input() == EOF) {
                         /* Produce an error, unclosed {{ */
                       }
                     }
   ```

Comment: I'm using Flex 2.5.35, which does seem to support non-greedy matches, infact I was able to get this working by replacing the 'add_code_line' pattern with `<CODE_FRAG>.*?/"}}" { add_code_line(yytext); }` and `<CODE_FRAG>.*? { add_code_line(yytext); }`. I'm still not sure whether that is a "good" flex solution to this problem.

Comment: @kfsone: I didn't say it rejects non-greedy-match syntax. Try verifying that it is actually doing a non-greedy match by using, for example, `{{code block1}} not a code block {{code block2}}` and seeing what you get.

Comment: Ah - got it now. Your point 3 was correct (don't need nested {{...}}).  I was hoping to avoid doing it with a gnarly regex but regex it is, thanks!